# How to write variable in haml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I'm trying to use haml on RoR.

I faced some problems in haml.

My sample code is below.

ERB:

```
<p> <div class="hello"> <%= @sample.val %> <%= @hogehoge.val %> </div> </p>
```

HAML:

```
%p
  .hello
    = @sample.val
    = @hogehoge.val
```

I can write one line in erb file.

But, I have to write 4 lines in haml.

Haml is so smart and beautiful syntacx structure, isn't it?

But I think writing so many lines is not smart.

How do I write in one line in haml in this case.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't like the way haml work, why do you use it? that's how haml work. If you want something different you need something different, there are more template languages.

You complain about the amount of line but think about the amount of characters and readability, maintainability. The amout of line is one of the less important things on your code, or do you write all your html code in one line when you use erb or plain html?

You could save a few line though doing:

```
%p
  .hello= "#{@sample.val} #{@hogehoge.val}"
```

but is it really THAT important? Well, now you have 2 lines instead of 1, is it "smart" enough? I don't think you can have that in one line using haml.

Answer (score 0):

> But, I have to write 4 lines in haml.

Yes, but you've saved a lot of characters and now have compile-time errors if you don't get your nesting right.  Don't focus on the lines used, but the clarity.

I *think* you can do this:

```
%p %div.hello
  = @sample.val + " " + @hogehoge.val
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.hello
   = @sample.val
   = @hogehoge.val
```

If you're using `<p>` for styling, you'd be better putting a `margin` property in your `.hello` css

You're missing the point of `haml` - it's less verbose than `erb`